# OCaml's utop: importing external modules

Tags: ocaml, utop

I'm interested in introducing [Angstrom](https://github.com/inhabitedtype/angstrom), a parsing combinator library, to a project of mine.

I installed Angstrom to my system with `opam` as follows:

```
$> opam install angstrom
```

I also successfully compiled the project with reference to the module in question using `ocamlfind`:

```
$> ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind -pkgs 'angstrom' project.byte
```

Surprisingly, I'm having trouble importing Angstrom to the `utop` repl. Commands like `#open Angstrom` indicate a value bound to the module name. I have searched for documentation of module imports from the repl, but I haven't found the result that I'm looking for.

**What's the best way to reference an external module from `utop`?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found an answer to my question. From `utop`:

```
utop # #require "angstrom";;
utop # open Angstrom;;
```

My apologies for perhaps posting prematurely, but hopefully someone will find this answer helpful in the future.